# How to use SSOCircle as an IDP for SSO service in bluemix?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, ibm-cloud

[SSOCircle](http://www.ssocircle.com/en/) provides a ready to use Identity Provider according to their website. I wanted to simulate SAML SSO and integrate it in sample Liberty for Java application in bluemix.

What I did so far:

1. Downloaded SSOCircle Public IDP Metadata from "Manage Metadata". Uploaded it into the bluemix SSO service via the upload file button and entered https://idp.ssocircle.com/sso in the textbox under "Step 1" in the SAML Enterprise setup.
2. Downloaded SAML metadata under "Step 2" in the SAML Enterprise setup and imported it in SSOCircle. The FQDN that I used is: https://ssocruzgstest-8iotczj2sk-cabc.iam.ibmcloud.com.

[image: SSOCircle Screenshot]

Edit** Changed URL to https://idp.ssocircle.com/sso/idpssoinit?metaAlias=/ssocircle&spEntityID=https://ssocruzgstest-8iotczj2sk-cabc.iam.ibmcloud.com/idaas/mtfim/sps/idaas/saml20 as recommended by Martin
[image: bluemix]

After integrating. I pointed my browser to https://cruzgsjava1.mybluemix.net then clicked "Sign in with SAML Enterprise".

I got redirected to https://idp.ssocircle.com/sso/UI/Login?module=peopleMembership&goto=https%3A%2F%2Fidp.ssocircle.com%2Fsso%2Fidpssoinit%3FmetaAlias%3D%2Fssocircle%26spEntityID%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fssocruzgstest-8iotczj2sk-cabc.iam.ibmcloud.com%2Fidaas%2Fmtfim%2Fsps%2Fidaas%2Fsaml20. I logged in and encountered an error

[image: Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URL is wrong. I have not seen clear documentation on ssocircle.com, but I found some samples from which I could deduce the (hopefully) right URL pattern. This is what I use for testing:

```
https://idp.ssocircle.com/sso/idpssoinit?metaAlias=/ssocircle&spEntityID=<your SP entity ID>;
```

You can find out your SP entity ID by downloading the service provider metadata in step 2 and inspect the attribute "entityID" of the root element "md:EntityDescriptor".

Comment: I changed the URL to https://idp.ssocircle.com/sso/idpssoinit?metaAlias=/ssocircle&spEntityID=https://ssocruzgstest-8iotczj2sk-cabc.iam.ibmcloud.com/idaas/mtfim/sps/idaas/saml20. I logged in but encountered an error.

FBTSML236E The assertion issued by http://idp.ssocircle.com could not be validated or decrypted.

I checked "My SAML Federations" in SSOCircle and the service provider URL showed up in there.

Comment: Yes, I also get this error message at that step. I have not found a way to get around that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The SSOCircle URL is correct. The error happens at the bluemix site. According to IBM knowledge center FBTSML236E says that the trace log will indicate the operation failed.

Most probably the validation of the assertion signature is failing. SSOCircle signing certificate itself is not self-signed but is signed by its own CA.
It could be the case that bluemix is validating the whole certificate chain and for that reason needs the CA certificate. You can get it from the SSOCircle web site after logging in and then under ['My certificate status'](https://idp.ssocircle.com/sso/hos/CertStatus.jsp) you'll find a link to the CA certificate.

If that does not solve the problem. Check with IBM how the SAML response is validated. SSOCircle public IDP by default signs the SAML assertion. It could potentially be that bluemix has different requirements (e.g. signing the SAML response)